# Upload and Save File in Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I need to upload a file when a button is clicked and the file should automatically save in a separate directory.

What I tried is:

```
Class Upload():
    def setupUi(self):
        ....

       self.upload_btn.clicked.connect(self.fileOpen)
    def fileOpen(self):
         file=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,'Open File',"F:\ ")
```

Comment: And what happened next?

Comment: What happened afterwards?

Comment: It isjust opening only.I want to directly save the upload file to a directory

Answer (score 0):

Use the python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module, something like:

```
import requests
files = {'upload_file': open('yourfile.name','rb')}
values = {'value_1': 'arg_1'}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=values)
```

Comment: I just want to open a file in a differnt folder and copy into another. Please help

Comment: You may shutil.copyfile func , take a look on https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile if required